# out of memory whilt using loadtxt

Tags: python

I try to use `loadtxt('x.txt', delimiter=' ')` on a file that is 6,8 GB in size. This gives a memory error. My computer have 8 GB memory. When I look at my computer performance meter I see that Python gives the error message already when just 3,4 GB of the memory is used. Why does not Python try to use the remaining 4,6 GB before giving in?

Yours!

Per P.

Comment: Which Python version are you running? Which OS?

Answer (score 3):

Is that `numpy.loadtxt`? Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L610), it pushes parsed lines (lists or tuples of specified type) into a list before packing it to array. This is going to consume a lot more memory than the size of the file, or even size of the packed `float` array containing values from file. I'd say it's unlikely you'll be able to load this file even with 64-bit Python on a 8 GB RAM machine.

Comment: It should work with SWAP partition. SWAP should work pretty good if you are using `for` loops over arrays/lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python is probably compiled in 32-bit architecture so it could not handle more than 4 GB of memory. To solve the problem install 64-bit Python on 64-bit OS.

PS. He gives up on 3.4 (not 4 GB) because some part of address space is reserved.

Comment: Fine, I will try the 64 bit version! Thanks!